# 2002 Chrysler Voyager 2.4 L stopped running

Tags: chrysler, timing

I replaced the water pump, timing belt, timing idler pulley and tensioner pulley and all the belt on an 2002 Chrysler Voyager 2.4L (interference motor). It ran great for few day until a few days ago that it stalled while driving. Won’t turn on, it cranks, but not run. I’m afraid it jumped timing. Scanned the Van and P0016 came up: CKP/CMP off timing, could be the sensors or the timing.

How can I check the timing without removing the entire bottom again? The timing marks are on the block and not the cover so the balancer has to come out, the side motor mount and more.

Also, with the code P0016, would you all say it’s the timing or the sensors?

I baptized this Van Murphy: if it can go wrong, it will.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already, ensure both the crank and cam sensors are plugged in correctly (push/prod the connectors onto their sockets).

If this doesn't do anything, pull each one separately and check them to ensure they are working correctly. Both sensors are 3-wire sensors, which means they are externally powered. You'll have to figure out which wire does what. The three wires will be: ground; power; signal. Ground could be black or green. Power could be red (or maybe with a stripe). Signal could be about any color. You can also test the wiring coming off of the connector (wire side) for power and ground, which would separate out the three distinctly. Once you have this figured out, power and ground the sensor (be careful, it could be a 5v signal ... 12v might over power it). Then connect the third to your DMM set to DC voltage (grounding the other side of your DMM). The wave a metal object (a wrench or screwdriver works great) in front of the sensor. As long as you see action on the DMM, you should be in good shape. If you don't, the sensor is most likely dead and will need replaced.

If all of that fails to produce results, then take your covers off and check timing. I'd suggest this *probably* isn't the issue, but could have happened. If you want to check this first, removing the covers to check cam timing shouldn't be *too* difficult, though I'd check to ensure your sensor connections are good first.